# How can I send an email using PHP?

Tags: php, email, wamp, wampserver

I am using PHP on a website and I want to add emailing functionality.

I have [WampServer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WampServer) installed.

How do I send an email using PHP?

Comment: Read [Manual](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 511, accepted):

It's possible using PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. Remember, the mail function will not work on a *local* server.

```
<?php
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com'       . "\r\n" .
                 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Reference:

- *[mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)*

Comment: what if i need to send a email from local server. i mean is there any way to access the nearest mailing server and make it send mail for me. i mean i can find the address of a yahoo mailing server and then i use that server for mailing purposes... is this possible?

Comment: You need to config SMTP on your local server. Take a look at this similar post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp

Comment: Hello @MuthuKumaran if that goes in spam is there any good solution for solving it, please answer.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman You can't solve the spam issue in PHP. Please ask a new question on the appropriate StackExchange site if this is still relevant.

Comment: How to make sure or verify if this works on my local server? If not possible methods to do so, suggest some alternatives please. thank you.

Comment: Just an addon to this answer...If you want to send an html message you should add to the header: '...Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n'.  And rememeber to add the new line before, like so: ...'\r\n Content-Type...'

Comment: You can download and run smtp4dev on windows to view emails on your development machine.

Comment: Can I make the letters come to the right folder?

Answer (score 140):

You could also use PHPMailer class at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer .

It allows you to use the mail function or use an smtp server transparently. It also handles HTML based emails and attachments so you don't have to write your own implementation.

The class is stable and it is used by many other projects like Drupal, SugarCRM, Yii, and Joomla!

Here is an example from the page above:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: If not using composer: `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; require_once('src/PHPMailer.php'); require_once('src/Exception.php');`

Comment: When using gmail on port 465 you'll need to set host to

`$mail->Host       = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';`

Answer (score 51):

If you are interested in html formatted email, make sure to pass `Content-type: text/html;` in the header. Example:

```
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

For more details, check php [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Comment: Hello, I tired this code, I added 3 recipients, one Hotmail, one Gmail, and one my website email. I received all except on Hotmail. Do you have an idea why it is not working for Hotmail?

Comment: Please check the spam folder in that case.

Comment: I already did, it is not in the spam, it is not reaching at all. I read a little more about the subject and it seems that Hotmail requires some special header or it does not allow the email to pass their servers... I still didn't find the solution though.

Comment: I solved my issue by using PHPMailer and entering my email account data with SSL in the email object of PHPMailer.

Comment: What if the message has HTML and php contents?

Answer (score 21):

Also look into the PEAR mail package [Pear Mail Page](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected)

It seems to be a little more robust than the standard mail() function that is built in (if the standard function isn't adequate).

Here is an excerpt from this page showing how it is used.  [PEAR Mail send() usage](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php)

```
<?php
    include('Mail.php');

    $recipients = 'joe@example.com';

    $headers['From']    = 'richard@example.com';
    $headers['To']      = 'joe@example.com';
    $headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

    $body = 'Test message';

    $smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.server.com";
    $smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
    $smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
    $smtpinfo["username"] = "smtp_user";
    $smtpinfo["password"] = "smtp_password";


    // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
    $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo); 

    $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
?>
```

Comment: please give an downloading link of your used mail.php link and all other associated file in an folder. Thanks

Comment: @Ashik The `Mail.php` file referenced in my example is part of the Pear Mail package. If you download and install the Pear Mail package, you will be able to include `Mail.php`. If you click on the 'Pear Mail Page' link above, there is a Download link with instructions.

Answer (score 15):

For most projects, I use [**Swift mailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/) these days. It's a very flexible and elegant object-oriented approach to sending emails, created by the same people who gave us the popular [**Symfony framework**](https://symfony.com/) and [**Twig template engine**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

---

### Basic usage :

```
require 'mail/swift_required.php';

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    // The subject of your email
    ->setSubject('Jane Doe sends you a message')
    // The from address(es)
    ->setFrom(array('jane.doe@gmail.com' => 'Jane Doe'))
    // The to address(es)
    ->setTo(array('frank.stevens@gmail.com' => 'Frank Stevens'))
    // Here, you put the content of your email
    ->setBody('<h3>New message</h3><p>Here goes the rest of my message</p>', 'text/html');

if (Swift_Mailer::newInstance(Swift_MailTransport::newInstance())->send($message)) {
    echo json_encode([
        "status" => "OK",
        "message" => 'Your message has been sent!'
    ], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} else {
    echo json_encode([
        "status" => "error",
        "message" => 'Oops! Something went wrong!'
    ], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

See [**the official documentation**](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) for more info on how to use Swift mailer.

Comment: Hi. You said `Swift_MailTransport` when your link to documentation says `Swift_SendmailTransport`. Does it mean you were referring to older version of swift mailer or it is a typo, or maybe I misunderstand something? I need to install older version of swift-mailer because I don't have php7 on my server. So I need to know if the documentation for current version would go with older version of the package. Thanks.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev : My answer was the correct way to do things 2 years ago, but [Swift_MailTransport has been deprecated since Swiftmailer v5.4.5](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/866). Anyway, if you can't use PHP 7 for your project, you should go with Swiftmailer v5.4.9. That's the last stable version that still supports PHP 5. For the documentation of version v5.4.9 or details on differences between v5.4.9 and v6.0.2, you might want to contact [Fabien Potencier](https://twitter.com/fabpot) or raise an issue [on Github](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer).

Comment: Thank you very much. So there is no documentation feely available for older version, when the distributives are available. Good to know.

Answer (score 14):

For future readers: Try this if other answers don't work (As was the case with me):

1.) Download [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), open the zip file and extract the folder to your project directory.

3.) Rename the extracted directory to **PHPMailer** and write the below code inside of your php script (the script must be outside of the **PHPMailer** folder)

```
<?php
// PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
// Base files 
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
// create object of PHPMailer class with boolean parameter which sets/unsets exception.
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              
try {
    $mail->isSMTP(); // using SMTP protocol                                     
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP host as gmail 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // enable smtp authentication                             
    $mail->Username = 'sender@gmail.com';  // sender gmail host              
    $mail->Password = 'password'; // sender gmail host password                          
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  // for encrypted connection                           
    $mail->Port = 587;   // port for SMTP     

    $mail->setFrom('sender@gmail.com', "Sender"); // sender's email and name
    $mail->addAddress('receiver@gmail.com', "Receiver");  // receiver's email and name

    $mail->Subject = 'Test subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'Test body';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) { // handle error.
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 13):

The core way to send emails from PHP is to use its built in `mail()` function, but there are a couple of ready-to-use SDKs which can ease the integration:

1. [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/)
2. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
3. [Pepipost](https://github.com/pepipost/pepipost-sdk-php) (works over HTTP hence SMTP port block issue can be avoided)
4. [Sendmail](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/open-source-email-solution)

P.S. I am employed with Pepipost.

Comment: You are employed with Pepipost and you put Pepipost at no.3. +1

Comment: @GeneCode, If something is best, then it is. It doesn't matter whether you're employed with them or not :)

Swiftmailer and PHPMailer, are definitely one of the best open source tools for sending emails (hence I kept them in 1 and 2). But, at the same time, they have certain limitations and blockers which we tried to address in our Pepipost SDK.

Comment: @DibyaSahoo that reflects highly on you

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

this is very basic method to send plain text email using mail function.

```
<?php
$to = 'SomeOtherEmailAddress@Domain.com';
$subject = 'This is subject';
$message = 'This is body of email';
$from = "From: FirstName LastName <SomeEmailAddress@Domain.com>";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$from);
```

Answer (score 8):

The native PHP function `mail()` does not work for me. It issues the message:

> 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send
>   to a non-local e-mail address

So, I usually use `PHPMailer` package

I've downloaded the version 5.2.23 from: [GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/v5.2.23.zip).

I've just picked 2 files and put them in my source PHP root

> class.phpmailer.php
>     class.smtp.php

In PHP, the file needs to be added

```
require_once('class.smtp.php');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
```

After this, it's just code:

```
require_once('class.smtp.php');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
... 
//----------------------------------------------
// Send an e-mail. Returns true if successful 
//
//   $to - destination
//   $nameto - destination name
//   $subject - e-mail subject
//   $message - HTML e-mail body
//   altmess - text alternative for HTML.
//----------------------------------------------
function sendmail($to,$nameto,$subject,$message,$altmess)  {

  $from  = "yourcontact@yourdomain.com";
  $namefrom = "yourname";
  $mail = new PHPMailer();  
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->isSMTP();   // by SMTP
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;   // user and password
  $mail->Host       = "localhost";
  $mail->Port       = 25;
  $mail->Username   = $from;  
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "";    // options: 'ssl', 'tls' , ''  
  $mail->setFrom($from,$namefrom);   // From (origin)
  $mail->addCC($from,$namefrom);      // There is also addBCC
  $mail->Subject  = $subject;
  $mail->AltBody  = $altmess;
  $mail->Body = $message;
  $mail->isHTML();   // Set HTML type
//$mail->addAttachment("attachment");  
  $mail->addAddress($to, $nameto);
  return $mail->send();
}
```

It works like a charm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have the same suggestion as @norteo indicated in his answer. Please keep in mind that v5.2 is deprecated and not receiving security updates. For v6 you can directly require: `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; require_once('src/PHPMailer.php'); require_once('src/Exception.php');`

Answer (score 6):

Full code example..

Try it once..

```
<?php
// Multiple recipients
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma

// Subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// Message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a mail web service such as Postmark, Sendgrid etc.

[Sendgrid vs Postmark vs Amazon SES and other email/SMTP API providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798141/sendgrid-vs-postmark-vs-amazon-ses-and-other-email-smtp-api-providers)

Edit: I just use the [Google Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=sv) now. I had trouble sending reminder email to my employer's organization due to strict filters. But Gmail works as long as you don't spam people.

Answer (score 3):

**Sent the Email with this script**

```
<h2>Test Mail</h2>
<?php

if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click To send mail">
  </form>
  <?php
  }

else

  {

  if (isset($_POST["from"]))
    {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

    mail("Test@example.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending an email";
    }
  }
?>
```

Once you press the Send email button, the email will be sent to Test@example.com

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
include "db_conn.php";//connection file
require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";// it will be in PHPMailer
require "class.smtp.php";// it will be in PHPMailer
require "class.phpmailer.php";// it will be in PHPMailer


$response = array();
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if(!empty($params->email_id)){

    $email_id = $params->email_id;
    $flag=false;
    echo "something";
    if(!filter_var($email_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $response['ERROR']='EMAIL address format error'; 
        echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        return;
    }
    $sql="SELECT * from sales where email_id ='$email_id' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $to = "demo@gmail.com";
    $subject = "DEMO Subject";
    $messageBody ="demo message .";

    if($count ==0){
        $response["valid"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "User is not registered yet";
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }

    else {

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->IsHTML(true); 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';//turn on to send html email
        // $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.zoho.com";
        $mail->Host = "p3plcpnl0749.prod.phx3.secureserver.net";//you can use gmail 
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->Username = "demousername@example.com";
        $mail->Password = "demopassword";
        $mail->SetFrom("demousername@example.com", "Any demo alert");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->Body = $messageBody;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        echo "yes";

        if(!$mail->send()) {
           echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       } 
       else {
           echo "Message has been sent successfully";
      }
    }

}
else{
    $response["valid"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}


?>
```

The above code is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Procedure for to send a user password via email using PHPMailer :**

**Step 1: First, Download PHPMailer Package from GitHub**

You can just download the PHPMailer source files and include the required files manually.

You can download the ZIP file with the source code from the PHPMailer homepage[1],
clicking on the “Clone or download” green button (on the right) and then selecting “Download ZIP”.
Unzip the package inside the directory where you want to save the source files.

[1] https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

**Step 2: Then, open (From Gmail Address) Google Account and do the following steps:**

1. Disable Two factor password verification in google account.
2. Turn on Less Security.
3. Allow third party app.

**Step 3: Try to use below Code (Note: Here, I have provided only the functional code for to send a user password via email using PHP and MySQL)**

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;  //add use in starting of the code

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '[Enter your Database Name]'); // connect to database

    if (isset($_POST['forgot_btn'])) {
        forgotpassword();
    }

    function forgotpassword(){
    global $db;
     
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users where user_id='$user_id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $fetch_user_id=$row['user_id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $email_id=$row['email_id'];
        $password=$row['password'];
        if($user_id==$fetch_user_id) {
       require '../PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';  //Please correctly mention the PHPMailer installed directory (Don't follow my directory)

    $mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    try{
       $mail->setFrom('[Enter your From Email_Address]', '[Enter Sender Name]');
       $mail->addAddress($email_id, $name);  //[To Email Address and Name]
       $mail->Subject = 'Regarding Forgot Password';
       $mail->Body = 'Hi '.$name.',Your Login Password is:'.$password.'';
       $mail->isSMTP();
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
       $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
       $mail->Username = '[Enter your From Email_Address]';
       $mail->Password = '[Enter your From Email_Address -> Password]';
       $mail->Port = 587;
       
       if($mail->send())
       {
          echo "<script>alert('Password Sent Successfully');</script>"; 
       }
       else
       {
         echo "<script>alert('Please Check Your Internet Connection or From Email Address/Password or Wrong To Email Address');</script>";   
       }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
       echo "<script>alert('Please Check Your Internet Connection or From Email Address/Password or Wrong To Email Address');</script>";
    }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Refer to these docs[1] for further information:

[1]. https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/

Comment: Giving Instructions to disable 2FA and turning on less security and as such endangering others accounts is if not malicious at least negligent. 
Instead adding an App-Password should work, while keeping the account in a less insecure state.

Comment: Hi @Skgland, Sorry to ask this, you mentioned App-Password should work right. Could you please tell me how to use that in this code?

Comment: Instead of disabling 2FA and turning on less security, you can create an App-Password which is then used instead of your Account password. 
I just Tested it with source code from above, though reduced to not use a db and simply sending a static email, for testing, also I needed to replace the required line as I couldn't fine the autoloder.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a **TESTE IF you NEED it** do it through tinker as the following code

```
# SSH into droplet
# go to project
$ php artisan tinker
$ Mail::send('errors.401', [], function ($message) { $message->to('emmanuelbarturen@gmail.com')->subject('this works!'); });
# check your mailbox
```

Answer (score 0):

**Email with plain text**

```
<?php

$to       = 'name@example.com';
$subject  = 'Your email subject here';
$message  = 'Your message here';

// Carriage return type (RFC).
$eol = "\r\n";

$headers  = "Reply-To: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Return-Path: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "From: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Organization: Hostinger".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP".phpversion().$eol;


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Email with html**

```
<?php

$to       = 'name@example.com';
$subject  = 'Your email subject here';
$message  = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Your '.$to.' as your contact email address</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi, there!</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that '.$to.' reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout</p>
</body>
</html>
';

// Carriage return type (RFC).
$eol = "\r\n";

$headers  = "Reply-To: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Return-Path: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "From: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Organization: Hostinger".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP".phpversion().$eol;


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Email with attachment**

```
<?php

$url = "https://c.xkcd.com/random/comic/";
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// $a will contain all headers.
$a = curl_exec($ch);
// This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL.
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

$str  = file_get_contents($url.'info.0.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// Get file info.
$imageTitle = $json['title'];

// Image url.
$imageUrl = $json['img'];

// Image alt text.
$imageAlt = $json['alt'];

// Image file.
$imageFile = file_get_contents($imageUrl);

$tokens = explode('/', $imageUrl);

// File name.
$fileName = $tokens[(count($tokens) - 1)];

// File extension.
$ext = explode(".", $fileName);

// File type.
$fileType = $ext[1];

// File size.
$header = get_headers($imageUrl, true);

$fileSize = $header['Content-Length'];




$to      = 'name@example.com';
$subject = "Enjoy reading today's most interesting XKCD comics";
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Your email '.$to.' is listed in our XKCD comics subscribers.</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1>'.$imageTitle.'</h1>
    <img src='.$imageUrl.' alt='.$imageAlt.'>
</body>
</html>';

// File.
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($imageFile));

// A random hash will be necessary to send mixed content.
$semiRand     = md5(time());
$mimeBoundary = '==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semiRand}x';

// Carriage return type (RFC).
$eol = "\r\n";

$headers  = 'Reply-To: Name <name@example.com>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Name <name@example.com>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'From: Name <name@example.com>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Organization: Hostinger'.$eol;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"".$eol;
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'.$eol;
$headers .= 'X-Priority: 3'.$eol;
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP'.phpversion().$eol;

// Message.
$body  = '--'.$mimeBoundary.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"".$eol;
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// Attachment.
$body .= '--'.$mimeBoundary.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type:{$fileType}; name=\"{$fileName}\"".$eol;
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'.$eol;
$body .= "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$fileName}\"".$eol;
$body .= 'X-Attachment-Id: '.rand(1000, 99999).$eol;
$body .= $content.$eol;
$body .= '--'.$mimeBoundary.'--';

$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if ($success === false) {
    echo '<h3>Failure</h3>';
    echo '<p>Failed to send email to '.$to.'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Your email has been sent to '.$to.' successfully.</p>';
}
```

**Email verification**

```
<?php

function verifyLink() {
    require 'db-connection.php';

    $mysqli->select_db($dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT `email`, `hash` FROM `Users` ORDER BY `active`";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== '' && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') {
    return '<a href="https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/verify.php?email='.$row[0].'&hash='.$row[1].'">Verify contact email</a>';
    } else {
    return '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/verify.php?email='.$row[0].'&hash='.$row[1].'">Verify contact email</a>';
    }

    $mysqli->close();
    
}

$to       = 'name@example.com';
$subject  = 'Verify your XKCD contact email address';
$message  = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Verify '.$to.' as your contact email address</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hi, there!</p>
<p>Please verify that you want to use '.$to.' as the contact email address for your XKCD account</p>
<p>XKCD will use this email to tell you about interesting comics updates.</p>
<div>'.verifyLink().'</div>
<h3>Do not recognise this activity?</h3>
<p>If you did not add '.$to.' to your XKCD account, ignore this email and that address will not be added to your XKCD account. Someone may have made a mistake while typing their own email address.</p>
</body>
</html>
';

// Carriage return type (RFC).
$eol = "\r\n";

$headers  = "Reply-To: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Return-Path: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "From: Name <name@example.com>".$eol;
$headers .= "Organization: Hostinger".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3".$eol;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP".phpversion().$eol;


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my fast time i had the same issues but after a proper resear i solved it. here is my approach. You have to  download the PHPMailer source files and include the required files manually in your project.

You can download the ZIP file with the source code from the PHPMailer homepage[1](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), clicking on the “Clone or download” green button (on the right) and then selecting “Download ZIP”. Unzip the package inside the directory where you want to save the source files.

[1](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) [from: GitHub.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Step 2: Then, open (From Gmail Address) Google Account and do the following steps:

**Disable Two factor password verification in google account.**

- Turn on Less Security.
- Allow third party app.
  There you Go..

  ```
   <?php

   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
   require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

   session_start();

   if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $subject = $_POST['subject'];
       $message = "I am trying";

           //Load composer's autoloader

           $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
           try {
               //Server settings
               $mail->isSMTP();
               $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
               $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
               $mail->Username = 'youremail@gmail.com';
               $mail->Password = 'password';
               $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                   'ssl' => array(
                       'verify_peer' => false,
                       'verify_peer_name' => false,
                       'allow_self_signed' => true
                   )
               );
               $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
               $mail->Port = 465;

               //Send Email
               $mail->setFrom('youremail@gmail.com');

               //Recipients
               $mail->addAddress($email);
               $mail->addReplyTo('youremail@gmail.com');

               //Content
               $mail->isHTML(true);
               $mail->Subject = $subject;
               $mail->Body    = $message;

               $mail->send();

               $_SESSION['result'] = 'Message has been sent';
               $_SESSION['status'] = 'ok';
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               $_SESSION['result'] = 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
               $_SESSION['status'] = 'error';
               echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           }
   }
   header("location: forgotPassword.php");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method in cPanel and everything worked fine:

```php
<?php 
  $dest = "destination@domain.tld"; 
  $fromaddy = "cpaneluser@domain.tld"; 
  mail("<$dest>","Test from php mail","Test","From:<$fromaddy>","-f$fromaddy"); 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "in cPanel"? Cannot you code be used in any php file?

Answer (score -1):

```
   $emailTextHtml='<h1>email sent from php use by phpmailer</h1>';

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                          // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'demo@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username of gmail
    $mail->Password = '2345678';                           // SMTP password of gmail
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('anupam@gmail.com', 'study'); // provide your gmail username 
    $mail->addAddress('komal@gmail.com', 'study');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('anupamverma@gmail.com', 'Information');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                          // Set email format to HTML
     $mail->Subject = 'Register client details and total client details';
     $mail->Body= "$emailTextHtml";    //write the html code
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```