# Is there a way to get the release notes emailed to someone when a version is released?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to have JIRA send an email to users or an email group when I click on the Release button of a version? This is an action that we currently do manually multiple times per week. It would be great if JIRA could email the group the release notes or just an email.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried modifying the Manage Versions functionality before and had problems now that it is a bundled plugin. I think the email could just have a link to the Release Notes or Change Log project reports. But for the actual functionality of this I think I might be tempted to have a cron job run a script looking for changes and do the mailing from there.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround can add a js script to jira's `Announcement Banner`, which executes on every screen:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // read release notes
    var notes = $('#release_notet_id').text();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#submit_bottun_id').length) {
            $.post('//email.web.server/send_email',{
                'type':'release',
                'content': notes
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then, on the email web server generate and send the email ([php example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-mail-using-php)). We don't have the Kanban plugin, so I don't have the actual IDs, just replace the actual IDs with the ones in the code snippet.