# PHP POST method, doesnt send email

Tags: php, html

I need some help. I have a contact formulary for a website, but it isnt sending the email, however the message I programmed to tell its working, popa up right.

Heres the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="CSS/Principal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
</header>
<section class="formulario">
    <form action="contacto.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre, Apellido y/o escuela" required="" />
        <label for="email">Email:<br>
        </label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@nightjunkies" required="" />
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
        <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" required>    </textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
      </p>
    </form>

  </section>

</body>
<footer>
<p class="footer">Powered By Xanmaya&copy;
</footer>
</html>
```

And here`s the PHP used

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$para = 'villasantdesign@gmail.com';
$titulo = 'ASUNTO DEL MENSAJE';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {
echo "<script language='javascript'>
alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
window.location.href = 'http://nightjunkies.com.mx';
</script>";
} else {
echo 'Falló el envio';
}
}
?>
```

Ill appreciate some help

Finally I fixed it using PHPMailer instead

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
if(isset($_POST["submit"] ))
{
    $nombrede = "Administrador";
    $de = 'example@domain.com';
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.net';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'example@mydomain.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->Port = 80;

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $nombre;
    $mail->addAddress($de, $nombrede);

    $mail->Subject = "Contacto Night Junkies";
    $mail->Body = $mensaje;

    if($mail->Send())
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
window.location.href = 'http://nightjunkies.com.mx';
</script>";
    } else {
        echo 'Hubo un problema';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;


}
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You're using the user's posted email address as your `From:` address. Your ISP is almost certainly blocking that because it doesn't exist on their server.

Comment: You can use a server-side redirect instead of using JavaScript for that.

Comment: no problem with the javascript. it works well.

Comment: No problem, but also not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons this might not work. How is PHP configured to handle `mail()`? Does that work from the server? You're also likely raising SPAM flags or simply being blocked. A better way to send reliable email is to setup an SMTP account and send the mail from that authenticated account. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) may help speed things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are trying to send the email from the receivers email. you can do this.

replace $header = 'From: ' . $email;

with $header = 'From: ' . $para;

and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe you run it in **localhost** or **local server**. try online and add this lines:

```
$headers .= "Cc: VALID@EMAIL.COM\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Besides, you should type valid email as a SENDER, as in your code:

```
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
```

UPDATED 2:

```
<?php
$email_reciever='reciever@emailvalid.com'; // user's email that fills the form

$to = $email_reciever;
$subject = 'ASUNTO DEL MENSAJE';
$headers = "From: NightJunkies <sender@validemail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: sender@validemail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message = 'Hello, friend!';
$message .= "</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "<script>alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias!');</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://nightjunkies.com.mx'>";
?>
```

if it is **not valid sender email**, receiver's server will ignore it even not receive it. dont forget to see in junk or spam folder

Check also here for **[mail format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)**

Comment: check again my answer in updated 2 and please don't use other things first. just use the codes in a single page to test.
if you have error found or reported, pls let me know

Comment: I think Im gonna search for another method. I dont know if it is a server problem.