# Link an html form to send an email

Tags: php, html

I am using a website template that comes with a good looking html form built in.
The problem is that it is not setup 100% nor working.

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                  <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block">Send message</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

            </div>
```

I would like that to send an email to a certain address. Do I need a separate php file?

Thanks,
James

Comment: You really need to learn the basics of PHP before you go any further.

Comment: Teaching you the basics is a job for an introductory tutorial, not for Stackoverflow. It isn't working because you haven't written any PHP code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your button should be:

```
<button type="submit" class="">Send message</button>
```

*Notice the *type="submit"*

---

EDIT:

For getting it to work just create a new PHP document called "sendemail.php" with this code:

```
<?php
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Now your action in your form should be:

```
<form action="sendemail.php">
```

Make sure that for each  you have in your form named the way you should like:

```
<input name="email" />
<input name="subject" />
etc....
```

Comment: Added that but still clicking 'submit' does nothing.

Comment: @chipyzs try adding method="post" to your <form> tag

Comment: Still not working. Don't you need a separate php send script or something like that?

Comment: @chipyzs Also your action will not work, you need some PHP script to get it to work, you can't just send emails like this. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but how would I integrate that? A separate .php file or in the same file? How do I tell html to look there for the information?

Comment: [`mailto:` URIs are ineffective as form actions](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) and should not be used. That PHP code is going to turn any server it is hosted on into a spam relay.

Comment: You've removed the bad `mailto:` advice, but the change you suggest to the button is pointless (submit is the default type) and your PHP is still a spam relay.

Answer (score -1):

inside your form tag add

```
action="mailto:emailadress@gmail.com"

<form action="mailto:emailadress@gmail.com"/>
```

Comment: Try using <input type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block" value="Send message"/> ?

Comment: Added that: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block" value="Send message"/> . the page loads and displays the form but when you click it nothing happens

Comment: That's weird.. Do you have your site online so I can look at the source code because from what I can see above it should work.

Comment: I don't get why it doesn't work, sorry :/ . It should. 
Have you tried the input type="submit" too?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block">Send message</button> which part should i add or change?

Comment: try deleting the <button></button>
and use the <input type=submit class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block" value="Send message"/>

Comment: [`mailto:` URIs are ineffective as form actions](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) and should not be used

Comment: <input type=submit class="btn btn-theme btn-lg btn-block" value="Send message"/> did not work and quentin how do you suggest I do it then?

Comment: @chipyzs  — You tagged the question *php*. Use that.

Comment: @FrederikVanHooghten — It could work, but usually won't, and having a form that doesn't work for most visitors isn't a good idea.

Comment: Added some php code that works above it  but how would I keep the same formatting as the form below?