# Submitting a form to PHP (which sends an email with the information) and then again to Salesforce web to lead

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Basically I need to have my form when submitted send an email via my php file and then send the data again to salesforce via web to lead.

basically I just need my form to run these two actions.

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="*****">
```

&

```
  <form action="/sendRequest.php" method="POST" role="form">
```

what is the best method to do this, I have heard AJAX but I am a noob.

Comment: Use second option for `<form>` and in `sendRequest.php` send e-mail and also send POST request to salesforce with CURL. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) question should help with CURL and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php) with sending e-mail.

Comment: I am a noob can you show me an example?

Comment: First you really should try it yourself. Otherwise you won't learn much if I show it to you. Let me see what you can come up with and then I'll help you.