# Email form not sending message

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm trying to set up the contact form of my site.
The script uses the template `contact_me.php`. The relevant excerpt of the form here:

```
// create email body and send it    
$to = 'jose.alberto.lara@gmail.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "Contacto con Ecopolíticas:  $name"; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website's contact form.\n\n"."Here 
are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nEmail: 
$email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@ecopoliticas.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
```

When I fill the form it seems to work; however, I don't receive any mail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Congratulations, you have formatted the code properly! Unfortunately, you forgot to add the language tag. I think this is PHP, am I right? I've cleaned the question to make it more readable and upvoted to encourage you keeping up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
sudo apt-get install sendgmail
```

did the work. It was not installed in my server.

Answer (score 0):

Everything with code is fine. You should know that function mail() won't send mail when it is run by local server. Here is proof: [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php).

If you want to send mail even with local server you should use phpmailer.

EDIT: Also I think if you install [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) it will work on local server.

Comment: The site is not in a local server, but thank you for the tip.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the dot (`.`) in:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
```

Comment: You are right, I removed the dot, yet the problem persists.

Comment: uh. `.=` is perfectly legal PHP. `$x .= 'foo'` is a shortcut for `$x = $x . 'foo'`;