# Sending Mail in php from localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send mail through PHP without using SMTP server like gmail. It should be send from localhost only.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the `mail()` function?

Comment: No without smtp no one api send real mail from localhost.

Comment: I have tried using mail() function and configured php.ini file for that.But no luck

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: if your server is *nix, you could possibly use something like `system("sendmail ...")`. though i don't know about possible security problems with that approach. see http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html

Comment: I don't think you know what SMTP is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send mail only **to** local users on a *nix system, you can use the systems `mail` command. It would work like this:

```
$pp = popen('mail -s "subject" jdoe', 'w');
fwrite($pp, $content);
pclose($pp);
```

where subject is to be replaced with the actual subject, jdoe with the target user account and `$content` should hold the desired content.

Every other way of sending mail involves SMTP. If you do not want to use `mail()` or an API, you will have to implement it yourself on sockets basis.