# adding message to php mail function

Tags: php, function, email

I am using this simple php mail function and I would like to add to message another text like "this message is from website".

```
$email="kontakt@fotografernevesterbro.dk";
$from=$_POST["email"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];
$message=$_POST["message"] + $sitemessage;
$sitemessage= "this is message from website";

mail ($email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);
```

I tried to add another variable and put it into mail function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.` to concatenate (not `+`) and `$sitemessage` should be appended to `$message` after it has been assigned a value.

```
$email="kontakt@fotografernevesterbro.dk";
$from=$_POST["email"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];
$sitemessage= "this is message from website";
$message=$_POST["message"] . $sitemessage;

mail ($email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will simply do what you want.

```
  $email="kontakt@fotografernevesterbro.dk";
    $from=$_POST["email"];
    $subject=$_POST["subject"];
    $headers = "From: $from  ";
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $message .= " this is message from website";

    mail ($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: *I have modified the code and tested.* - no you haven't. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016443/adding-message-to-php-mail-funcion#comment55792833_34016640)