# its possible to send email with PHP impersonating a user?

Tags: php, email

Suppose i have a UNIX system with an email section configured on php.ini that sets the sendmail_from to info@mysoft.com

It is possible to send an email with the PHP mail func to user1@gmail.com from user2@gmail.com?

I want the user1 to see in the FROM section of the receive email the user2 emails not he info@mysoft.com configured on the php.ini so when the user1 tries to reply the email it actually replies to user1@gmail.com

Is this possible with that function or any other? or even any other service?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php -- you could change the "from" and/or the "reply-to" depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you can see example 2 at official documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

need to set additional header