# PHP contact page not sending on Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom Wordpress theme and the contact page template wont process my **process.php** file to send mail.

The file is inside the theme folder.

However, on submission it redirects to the home page with the title of the page being **file not found**.

I also get this error in my MAMP access logs file:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2016:11:55:31 +0100] "POST /wordpress-4.5.3/wordpress/contact/process.php HTTP/1.1" 404 3384

The code that is within the **process.php** file looks like this:

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";

$subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);

$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

$number = htmlspecialchars($_POST['number']);

$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

$headers = "Senders email addresS: " . $email;
$headers .= "Senders number: " . $number;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

and the template contact file looks like this:

```
        <form method="post" action="process.php">

            <p> Name: * </p> 

            <input type="text" name="name" required> <br>

            <p> Email: * </p> 

            <input type="email" name="email"> <br>

            <p> Phone Number: * </p> 
            <input type="number" name="number"> <br>

            <p> Message: * </p> 

            <textarea name="message" required>  

            </textarea> <br> 

            <button type="submit" name="submit"> Send </button>             

        </form>
```

If anyone has any suggestions to help me fix this, I would greatly appreciate it, plus if you need any more information, let me know!

Many Thanks!

Comment: where you put the process.php file in wordpress. what is the path

Comment: @mollie C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress-4.5.3\wordpress\wp-content\themes\custom_wordpress

Comment: add this line <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/process.php"> than try please

Comment: @mollie Does not seem to work, bring up a blank page of the file path and the email does not send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change the action of the form 
add this action=<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/process.php"
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, bring up a blank page of the file path and the email does not send?

Comment: you put the comment that file not found. now page form redirected well.  Now you need to check your mail function. if live working Please print the <?php phpinfo(); ?> function and check PHP mail function.

Comment: also put the mail function in if(mail(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))){echo "mail send";}else{ echo "mail not send";}

Comment: It comes up with "Mail not sent" - when looking at the PHP varibles on PHPINFO it says "submit" has no value, does it need one?

Comment: ok check in phpinfo that mail enable and also why the mail not send, and please accept my answer.

Comment: I think you add wrong header Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php