# I want send a confirmation message on clicking on link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send activation confirmation message by link variable ,
here is my link http://polestarllp.com/users/useractive.php?contranumber=23215,
when user click on this link , i just want notify the admin by message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var person = "<?php $data; ?> ";
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser',
                     //type: 'Post',
                     data:person,
                     success: function (data, xhr) {
                     alert(data.ErrorMessage);
                     if(data.Success)
                     {
                    document.location.reload();  
                     }

                     },
                     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         console.log('Error in Operation');
                     }
                 });



         });
    </script>
<style>
```

**php code**

```
    <?php
  $data=$_GET['contranumber'];
?>
```

Comment: What happens when the link is clicked? Maybe echo `<?php $data; ?>`.

Comment: <?php
  $data=$_GET['contranumber'];
?>

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. That identifies that this code is also open to XSS injections. Is that your only PHP code??? What is this submitting to?

Comment: recently edited the code , i am trying to send confirmation message on http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser this  url API,  user have been activated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: 192.168.etc is only accessible locally. Describe your issue and provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest handling this by PHP code only.

When user opens the page (which effectively happens after clicking the link), php code will validate the request and send a notification / email / whatever required.

It would be safer as the logic (no XHR request in the background) will be hidden from public.

Comment: can you tell me how to save php variable in jquery @@var person = "<?php $data; ?> "; this code is not working , showing blank value  of person

Comment: @SanjayYadav you cannot just pass the variables between JavaScript and PHP. You need to kind of render it into javascript code, as the comment above suggests.

Comment: Hi BarT  K@@ Friend it working@@ var contranumber = <?php  echo json_encode($data); ?>;