# PHP mail not receiving using this code

Tags: javascript, php, html

This below code using for receive the email for password, but email not sent due to some error. Kindly review the code and corrected, update the new code for send email. We are using forgot password in html and validate and email using php.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        mysql_connect('localhost','connect','connect') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('connect') or die(mysql_error());
        $Email_Address = $_POST['Email_Address'];
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * from erp_ng_form_reg WHERE    Email_Address='$Email_Address' ") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        //$p = mysql_affected_rows();
        //$res = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $to = $result['Email_Address'];
        $message = $result['Password'];
        $subject="Remind password";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <teamzulu@indoffgroup.com>' . "\r\n"; 
        $m=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($m) {
            echo'Check your inbox in mail';
            echo $message;
        } else {
            echo  "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                   var abc  = document.getElementById('Email_Address').value;
                   alert(abc);</script>";
            echo 'mail is not send';
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                border:1px solid olive;
                border-radius:5px;
            }
            h1 {
                color:darkgreen;
                font-size:22px;
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Forgot Password<h1>
        <form action='#' method='post'>
            <table cellspacing='5' align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email Address:</td><td><input type='text' id='Email_Address' name='Email_Address'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error in this code ?

Comment: `print_r($result)` debug this ist, u will get the solution.

Comment: print_r($result) this is not in code.

Comment: LOL, `print_r()` is a function just for checking your `$result`, check what are you getting in `$result`...

Comment: before this line `$to = $result['Email_Address'];` use `print_r($result);` and share the result.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 35 [Licensee_Name] => team zulu [FACT_ERP_NG_Serial_Number] => 12304567890 [Email_Address] => teamzuluind@gmail.com [Password] => 12345 [Confirm_Password] => 12345 ) ) mail is not send

Comment: this is the result but error came "mail not sent"

Comment: sounds like, your mail function is not working on local. u need to configure it

Comment: Yes. I know, i configure this in server. due to some safety so i set localhost.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        mysql_connect('localhost','connect','connect') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('connect') or die(mysql_error());
        $Email_Address = $_POST['Email_Address'];
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * from erp_ng_form_reg WHERE    Email_Address='$Email_Address' ") or die(mysql_error());
        $numofemails = mysql_num_rows($q);
        if($numofemails > 0) {
            $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
            $to = $result['Email_Address'];
            $message = $result['Password'];
            $subject="Remind password";
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: <teamzulu@indoffgroup.com>' . "\r\n"; 
            $m = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            if($m) {
                echo'Check your inbox in mail';
                echo $message;
            } else {
                echo  "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                       var abc  = document.getElementById('Email_Address').value;
                       alert(abc);</script>";
                echo'mail is not send';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Email Not found';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: test this, may you not getting email id after query.

Comment: check your mail function is working on server or not?

$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text"; mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg); cehck by put the file on server with proper emailid.

Comment: all function configure to server. but mail not received.

Comment: try this one may authentication required! http://stackoverflow.com/a/23905054/1374160

Comment: yes. the mail function configure to server. but the mail not receiving till now.

Comment: First check by simple sending mail, mail receiving or not. if not received than check your mail server settings.

Comment: the password shown in page but the mail not received.

Comment: i am not configure SMTP. Is this problem for email not received?

Comment: the test email received from SMTP Configure.

Comment: please send me ur email i need ur help