# How to send a mail from twig template?

Tags: javascript, php, twig, bolt-cms

I just wanted to know if there is a way to send a mail from twig.
I have my templeate, there is 2 text boxes, one for the destination, and other one for the message. can anyone help me with it?

Or if there is a way that using JS, PHP or something like that with twig to do that?

Any kind help is welcome haha thanks

Comment: Twig is used to display data, not process it or modify it

Comment: But is there a way that using PHP o JS, or... don't know, something else, to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bolt (assumption based on the tag), then my suggestion would be to install the BoltForms (`bolt/boltforms`) extension.

Out of the box, it has a "default" example contact form (that you can safely remove from it's configuration, or modify to your needs) that you can ad to a template with:

```
{{ boltforms('contact') }}
```

The `contact` string tells BoltForms *which* named form from your configuration you want to use.

Also note, that Bolt uses Swiftmailer to handle emails, and it makes a best guess to configure itself by default, but you really should set the `mailoptions` parameters in your **main** Bolt configuration file