# How can I get my contact form live on a static website?

Tags: php, html, static, contact-form

I recently signed up to GoDaddy cPanel hosting and wanted my simple contact form live on my contact page. Here is the code for the form:

```
                    <div class "col-md-12">
                    <form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Name." /><br />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Email." /><br />
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30" placeholder="Message."></textarea><br />
                        </div>
                        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit." />
                    </form>
                </div>
```

I understand PHP is involved but I just need a push in the direction of what to include. The styling is also very basic.

Comment: Check this out: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: These two youtube tutorials are working: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMN-cl7EmIM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMXFMVg5E4U