# phplist send emails using cronjobs directadmin

Tags: php, directadmin, phplist

I installed phpList on my website. I am trying to make a cronjob in DirectAdmin which sends all the emails currently in the queue. I used the [following website](http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples.html) and tried some off the examples. I can't seem to get any of them to work.

The phpList is located at https://www.mydomainname.nl/lists/admin/

I think this is all the information you need? Let me know if there is any other data I can give you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of server are you using? Do you have access to log files?

Comment: @caramba it's an FTP server and it depends on what log files you are talking about

Comment: FTP only means how files get transported to the server (File Transfer Protocol) if you do `phpinfo()` you'll find out which server you're running on. Probably apache. On the `phpinfo()` dump search for `error_log` then you'll find a path from the log file. Have a look in the log file for the errors. If it is to big, remove all content. Try to send mail again, open that file again and see if you got an error...

Comment: @caramba it's an Apache server. error_log has no value

Comment: it can be many different reasons that it is not working... Try sending an email like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5335311/2008111 if that's not working you know it has nothing to do with phplist..

Comment: The emails are being sent, I'm just trying to make a cronjob to do it automatically.

Comment: Then try set up the cronjob to trigger that php file which is working. You need to go trough it step by step from the working parts to find out which is not working. When that works you actually just have to change the php src.