# Send an email using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email using php, but when I try it on browser I get error:

> "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later."

Here is my php file

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['n']) && isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['m']) ){
        $n = $_GET['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
        $e = $_GET['e'];
        $m = nl2br($_GET['m']);
        $to = "amal.soltni@esprit.tn";
        $from = $e;
        $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
        $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
                echo "success";
        } else {
                echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: Enable error reporting, ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 ); error_reporting( E_ALL ); than check

Comment: How are you sending mail? Are you using localhost?

Comment: @programmingArrow I am using Apache2 server

Comment: @Amal Are you testing it from your local server, Can you share the link which is calling this code?

Comment: @TausifAnwar http://45.55.229.122/amal/email.php?n=amal&e=amal.soltani@esprit.tn&m=test

Comment: Can you try the below code?

Comment: I don't see any error in your code, as you are getting error : "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.", this means your mail function is not executing. Check your mail server you are using to send mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one to send the mail and use live server to execute this code, don't use localhost to send the mail

```
    <?php
    if( isset($_GET['n']) && isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['m']) ){
    $n = $_GET['n']; 
    $e = $_GET['e'];
    $m = nl2br($_GET['m']);
    $to = "amal.soltni@esprit.tn";
    $from = $e;
    $subject = "My subject";
    $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';;
    $headers = 'From: .$from.' . '\r\n' .
    $send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   }else {
      echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Use var_dump($send); die("dead"); and share the response.

Comment: I used appache2 server and I'm not getting an error but I've not recieve any emai

Comment: I get "NULL dead"

Comment: can you add you gmail's email id in $to variable to test it?

Answer (score -1):

Please use this following code.

```
   <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $n = $_POST['n'];
        $e = $_POST['e'];
        $m = $_POST['m'];
        $to = "amal.soltni@esprit.tn";
        $from = $e;
        $subject = 'Contact Form Message';
        $message = '<b>Name:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
                echo "success";
        } else {
                echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

  ?>

  <form method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="n" placeholder="Name"><br>
  <input type="email" name="e" placeholder="Email"><br>
  <textarea col="10" rows="5"  name="m" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```