# Where do I put the send to email for this code for my contact form?

Tags: php

Where does my send to email go on this form?

```
<!--Start Contact form -->                                                      
<form action="email/" method="post" name="enq" target="_blank" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Your Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
    </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>                  
            <!--End Contact form -->
```

Comment: You do not define a send to email in your html. You will need to script it on the server side.

Comment: Can you take a look at here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP built-in `mail()` function for sending emails to one or more recipients dynamically from your PHP app either in a plain-text form or formatted HTML.

The basic syntax of the mail() function is as follows;

```
mail(to, subject, message, headers, parameters)
```

Easiest way to send emails from php

```
<?php
    $to = 'xyz@somedomain.com';
    $subject = 'This is subject';
    $message = 'This is email message'; 
    $from = 'sendermailadd@email.com';

    // Sending email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
        echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
    } else{
        echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
    }
?>
```

for further explained details please refer [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm)

---

> Please note that the PHP mail() function is a part of the PHP core but you **need to set up a mail server** on your machine to make it really work.

How to configure XAMPP to send mails from localhost [Read From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)