# How to send an HTML email, what contains a php echo command?

Tags: php, email, smtp, echo, send

I searched for this everywhere, but I couldn't find it. I want to echo some variables. My message:

```
$mailMsg ='<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#999999"  width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
   <tr  margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
   <td  margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
   <td class="header container" align=""  display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">&#13;
   &#13;
   </td>&#13;
   <td  margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
   </tr>&#13;
   </table>
   &#13;

   <table class="body-wrap" bgcolor=""  width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
   <tr  margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
   <td  margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
   <td class="container" align="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">&#13;
   &#13;

     <div class="content"  max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px;">&#13;
       <table  width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
         <tr  margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
           <td  margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
             <h1 line-height: 1.1; color: #000; font-weight: 200; font-size: 44px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0;">New purchase at Cali client!</h1>&#13;
     <p  font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">Email: </p>
     '
      + echo $useremail +
     '

  <br  margin: 0; padding: 0;" />&#13;
        <p  font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">Discord: </p>
        '+ echo $userdiscord +'
  <br  margin: 0; padding: 0;" />&#13;
        <p  font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">Ip: </p>
  '
  + echo $ip;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `+` to connect strings in PHP. Use `.` instead.

And there is no need to echo the variable.

So instead of

```
' + echo $useremail + '
```

do

```
' . $useremail . '
```

then the common way of sending mail in PHP: [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

You may also use placeholders in your HTML template and replace them with your vars then.

For example:

```
$mail_template = '<table><tr><td>##USERNAME##</td></tr></table>';
$mail_final = str_replace('##USERNAME##', $username, $mail_template);
// ...
mail($to, $subject, $mail_final, $headers);
```