# Input button won't send to Email

Tags: html, button, input

I am trying to set my "Submit" button to send to my email address but it doesn't seem to work. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing and haven't coded that much lately. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code which is live on my website - www.flyfreebird.com/aprons.html :

```
<div class="custom_form group">
 <form class="form_container">
 <form method="post" action="mailto:flyfreebird@me.com" enctype="text/plain">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="fullname">
  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone">
  <label for="company">Company</label>
  <input type="text" name="company">
  <label for="phone">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="quantity">
  <label for="zip">Zip</label>
  <input type="text" name="zip">
  <label for="details">Details</label>
  <textarea id="details" name="subject" placeholder="Tell us what we need to know…" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
```

Comment: mailto does not send an email. It just launch the default email client on user's machine. The email form will be pre-populated with the values from the form input but still the user have to click to send email out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send email with bare HTML, you should use PHP or something like that
[How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: what would that look like? I have no clue how to code PHP and wouldb;t know where to start. would using <a href="mailto:myemail@me.com"></a> work

Comment: I have no idea myself at the moment, search on internet send email in PHP or Javascript. It should contain SMTP or something like that. It's not so simple

Comment: Here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. Appreciate your help ;)