# How to email people a coupon code when they submit their email

Tags: email, github-pages

I have a static page hosted on GitHub pages that has a form for a user to fill out with their email, and I want to be able to send that email address a generic message back with a coupon code. (the code will be the same in every email.)

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Is there an easy to integrate service that can accomplish this?
2. If there is not a service for this, what other options are there?

EDIT: I know that there is a way to do it using PHP. If possible I would like to keep my site on github pages and have it communicate with an already existing service.

Comment: Are you asking about sending email? If so, try Mailgun, it's excellent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: I know that it is possible using PHP, I accidentally tagged it in the post originally. My question is does there already exist a service or API that can do it for me, and ideally interact with it using a form or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find any reliable service which offers this. There are two possibilities:

1. The API **does not** need an API key, so it can be used by anyone to send emails. Such a service would be used for spamming and won't fit your needs, because all messages will end up in the spam folder.
2. The API **does** need an API key, so you will have to expose the key to your users, which is a really bad idea, because someone could steal it and cause damage.

So, you will need to setup some sort of web server with a small API.