# Sending an email using HTML form

Tags: html

Here is my code.

```
<form action="MAILTO:example@gmail.com  " method="post" enctype="text/file">
   A3 or A4:<br>
   <input type="text" name="A3 or A4"><br>
   Add image:<br>
   <input type="file" name="image"><br>
   <input type="button" id=" value="click">
</form>
```

Issue: After Clicking the submit button or in this case just the button, nothing happens. I am currently using gmail so if you could please help.

Comment: This is just completely wrong. This isn't a capability of HTML. You'd need to use a server side language like PHP.

Comment: i tried PHP and JavaScript and nothing worked.

Comment: Are you trying to send an email from the user's own email client? or are you trying to send the email from your own server?

Comment: so when a customer fills out the form the form details get sent to me.

Comment: Yes so the approach you're trying to take will not work. You have to use something like PHP. Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php 

You have to use a web server with all the necessary email protocols such as SMTP, POP3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a button of `input type="button"` will not prompt the POST action. You should be using a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="click"/>
```

Second, `form action="MAILTO:  "` should be `form action="mailto:someone@example.com"`.

A simple [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail) perhaps could provide some insights. Yet, as you mentioned Gmail usage, I suggested reading [Gmail API Guides](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/) in which examples of various languages are provided.

Comment: I left the mailto blank because i didn't know what to put in as i didn't want to use my gmail.

Comment: @YALAYOLO If you checked the example from w3schools, you will find that the html is just calling your Outlook (or other email client you are using) with information from the form. 

Yet, I guess what you want is a simple button click on html form which will send all the messages+attachments to the target. Since this is more advance, I suggest you reading Gmail examples to see how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

The button should have type="submit"

```
<form action="mailto:" enctype="text/file" method="post">
A3 or A4:<br> 
<input name="A3 or A4" type="text"><br>
Add image:<br>
<input name="image" type="file"><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```