# PHP mail on submit

Tags: php, forms, email

I am trying to get a contact form using the built in [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to work but I'm running into some problems.

What I would like:

- On clicking 'submit' the form is sent to defined emailadres.php.
- If sent successfully, a confirmation message is displayed.
- If not sent, an error message is displayed.

What is currently happening:

- Confirmation message already shows on page load; regardless of form submission.
- Mail is not sent.

Code I'm using:

```php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from); 
    $sendErr = "Your message has been sent";
} else {
    $sendErr = "Your message could not be sent";
}
```

I'm fairly new to all this so any help figuring out where my thinking stalls would be appreciated. If I need to post more parts of the form I will.

Comment: first seach it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: you need [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library

Comment: Confirmation message is showing because you have put success message if the user clicks on submit. Whether your mail function runs or not the success message will be displayed. if you are running this on local server then it wont work u need to install mail server.

Comment: As @hungrykoala said, use PHPMailer, it is incredibly powerful

Comment: BTW: If you are using php mail(), your recipients may not get your email on the first attempt as of Greylisting. I propose to use a framework or a smtp-server instead of just php's inbuilt function.

Comment: I'm looking into it right now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using does not even check if the mail was sent successfully, it only checks it the formular was submitted. [mail()](http://php.net/mail) returns true if the mail was sent successfully, false if not. So you can check its return value:

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $sent = mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from); 

    // Check here if the mail was sent or not
    if ($sent) {
        $sendErr = "Your message has been sent";
    } else {
        $sendErr = "Your message could not be sent";
    }
}
```

Comment: And if it still doesn't work; try reading this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436/3578036