# How to send an email using php.to two different recipients. and two different contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am beginner to php and ajax. Could you please help me how to send an email using php. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is my required.

Logged in user details to AC Dealers and dealers content to logged in user.

The below image content should sent to logged in user details to the AC Dealer email id.
[image]

Comment: I think we need a bit more info. So you just want to send an Email in php with some text to a specific recipient?

Comment: @DavidGölzhäuser. yes exactly ..for example: if  john is logged in and he  seeing  dealers data .john details need to send to dealers email ..and which the data has john has seen that should need to send to john email.

Comment: I hope my answer helped you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Well, sending an Email in PHP is pretty easy.

**Sending from the server to an recipient:**

```
$recipient = "dealer@market.com";
$subject = "This is a very important subject";
$message = "This is the Email body with your data";
mail($recipient, $subject, $message);
```

**Sending from a specific Email to an recipient**

```
$recipient = "dealer@market.com";
$subject = "This is a very important subject";
$message = "This is the Email body with your data";
$header = "From: John Doe <john.doe@email.com>";
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $header);
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php).