# form with attachment - jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email-attachments

Hello I would like to attach a file and send it using jQuery AJAX and PHP, right now it just send the text, can some body help me about what it follows to attach  the file and send the email with it,

Then i will proceed with validations,

I will show the complete solution after achieve it

This is the form

```
           <form class="parte-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                <input type="text" class="txt-field txt-full pName" name="pName" placeholder="* Nombre" required="required">
                <div class="half-input-cont">
                    <input type="text" class="txt-field txt-half" name="pPhone" placeholder="Telefono">
                    <input type="text" class="txt-field txt-half" name="pEmail" placeholder="* Correo" required="required">
                </div> 
                <textarea class="txt-field txt-full txt-area" placeholder="Mensaje" name="pMsg"></textarea>
                <div class="input-cont">
                    <label class="txt-file" for="cv">Adjuntar C.V.<p>Seleccionar archivo</p> <span>No se ha elegido archivo</span></label> 
                    <input type="file" class="txt-file-btn" id="cv" name="pFile">
                </div>
                <div class="more-btn-cont form-btn-cont">
                    <input type="hidden" name="frm-action" value="par-form">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue-l btn-par" name="pPar" value="Enviar solicitud">
                </div> 
            </form>
```

this is the data preparation to be send - jQuery Ajax

```
$(data);
function data(){
    $('.btn-par').click(parte);
}

    function parte(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var data = $('.parte-form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "data/comp-actions.php",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 1) {
                    var name = $('.pName').val();
                    $('.popup-name').html(name)
                    $('.popup-send').removeClass('hidden'); 
                    $('.popup-close').click(function(){
                        $('.popup-send').addClass('hidden');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Error al enviar');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the data recollection and sender - PHP

```
    //Cotizar values
$pName = $_POST['pName'];
$pPhone = $_POST['pPhone'];
$pEmail = $_POST['pEmail'];
$pMsg = $_POST['pMsg']; 
$pPar = $_POST['pPar'];

 //File name 
$fileName = $_FILES['pFile']['name'];
$fileTmp = $_FILES['pFile']['tmp_name'];
$filePath = "files/".$fileName;

//File metadata
$fileType = $_FILES['pFile']['type'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['pFile']['size'];
// $fileError = $_FILES['pFile']['error'];


//Send mail
if($pName != "" && $pEmail != ""){
    $to = "my@email.com";
    $subject = "$pName Desea unirse al equipo";
    $headers = "From: $pEmail";
    $info = "$pName, se comunica con nosotros para unirse al equipo\n"
        . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . "Datos del solicitante\n"
        . "Nombre: $pName\n"
        . "Telefono: $pPhone\n"
        . "Email: $pEmail\n"
        . "mensaje: $pMsg\n"
        . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . "Datos del archivo\n"
        . "Archivo: $fileName\n"
        . "Tipo de archivo: $fileType\n"
        . "Tamaño del archivo: $fileSize\n"
        . "Ruta del archivo: $filePath\n"
        . "\n"   
        . "\n"
        . "\n";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $info, $headers)) {
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `FormData` to grab files

Comment: ##Thanks, I will try it I hope it works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FormData` to grab file contents as well

```
var form = $(".parte-form")[0];
var data = new FormData(form);
```

In your ajax call, set

```
processData: false
```

Comment: I dont have the reputation to vote, but thanks a lot :) I will try it, do i have to modify something in the php file?

Comment: You do not need to modify the php file.

Comment: after click send, its showing me this:  jquery-2.2.3.js:8998 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: Its not sending the email :'(

Comment: @CarlosTrejo apologies for the delay. Take a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php to send mail via PHP

Comment: Hoo dont worry and a lot of thanks Rotimi, I ve already achieve it, I will post my solution here :)

Answer (score 1):

## Here is my solution for this feature

**This solution could be improved I'm working on it if you have a better solution, please pot it or post the link to the solution**

File with the form, the call to your css and js files, in case of not need it you can remove the recaptcha div

```
<form class="parte-form" id="contact_body" method="POST" action="send-unete.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<input type="text" class="txt-field txt-full pName txt-text" name="pName" placeholder="* Nombre" required="required">
<div class="half-input-cont">  
    <input type="tel" class="txt-field txt-half txt-phone" name="pPhone" placeholder="Teléfono">
    <input type="email" class="txt-field txt-half" name="pEmail" placeholder="* Correo" required="required">
</div> 
<textarea class="txt-field txt-full txt-area" placeholder="Mensaje" name="pMsg"></textarea>
<div class="input-cont">
    <!-- it changes the style of the input type file -->
    <label class="txt-file" for="cv">Adjuntar C.V.<p>Seleccionar archivo</p> <span>No se ha elegido archivo</span></label> 
    <input type="file" class="txt-file-btn" id="cv" name="pFile[]">
</div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your key"></div>
<div class="more-btn-cont form-btn-cont">
    <!-- Set of email where the email will be send -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pEmailSet" value="<?php the_field( 'email_set_unete', 216) ?>">
    <!-- Identifies the form in case of have more forms or actions like save, delete, load etc -->
    <input type="hidden" name="frm-action" value="par-form">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue-l btn-par" name="pPar" value="Enviar solicitud">
</div> 
</form>
    <!-- Success popup -->
    <div class="popup-send layer hidden">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="popup-info">
                <div class="popup-title">
                    <p>Mensaje enviado</p>
                    <button class="popup-close">X</button>  
                </div>
                <p class="popup-msg"><b class="popup-bold popup-name"></b>, Tus datos han sido enviados al área correspondiente en la brevedad nos comunicaremos contigo, para darle seguimiento a tu petición, <b class="popup-bold">Gracias</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Error popup -->
    <div class="popup-error layer hidden">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="popup-info">
                <div class="popup-title">
                    <p>Mensaje no enviado</p>
                    <button class="popup-close">X</button>  
                </div>
                <p class="popup-msg"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- it gets the mail path of the site used for references -->
<p class="dir hidden"><?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?></p>
```

JS file with ajax call it recolects the data and prepar it for be reciebed by the php file

```
function data(){
    // Action function
    // $('.btn-cot').click(cotizar);
    $('.btn-par').click(parte);
}

    function parte(e){ 
        $("#contact_body").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
            proceed = true;
            
            //if everything's ok, continue with Ajax form submit
            if(proceed){ 
                var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
                var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
                var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
                $.ajax({ //ajax form submit
                    url : "data/comp-actions.php",
                    type: request_method,
                    data : form_data,
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false
                }).done(function(res){ //fetch server "json" messages when done
                    if(res == 1){
                        var name = $('.pName').val();
                        $('.popup-name').html(name)
                        $('.popup-send').removeClass('hidden'); 
                        $('.popup-close').click(function(){
                            $('.popup-send').addClass('hidden');
                        });
                    }else{
                        $(".popup-error").removeClass("hidden"), 
                        $(".popup-error .popup-msg").html('Tu mensaje no pudo ser enviado, te pedimos revises que hayas completado los <b class="popup-bold">campos requeridos (*)</b>, revisado que el archivo adjunto sea en <b class="popup-bold">formato pdf</b>, asi como marcado la <b class="popup-bold">casilla de verificación</b> y vuelvas a intentarlo, <b class="popup-bold">Gracias</b>'),
                        $(".popup-close").click(function() {
                            $(".popup-error").addClass("hidden");
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the comp-actions.php file, it checks the submited action and loads the needed file, the recaptchalib.php must be added in order to get the recaptcha response

```
include('recaptchalib.php');
//Action selector
$action = $_POST['frm-action']; 
$captchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if ($captchaResponse != "") {
    $captcha = 1;
    if($action == "cot-form" && $captcha == 1){
        include('send-cotizar.php');    
    } elseif($action == "par-form" && $captcha == 1){
        include('send-unete.php'); //**
    }elseif($captcha != 1){
        echo 0;
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

This is the send-unete.php file wich is loaded after the action check and prepare the data and attachment to be send it

```
$pEmailSet = $_POST['pEmailSet'];
$recipient_email    = $pEmailSet; //recepient
$fromUser = $_POST['pEmail'];
$from_email         = $fromUser; //from email using site domain.


if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
die('Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'); //exit script
}

if($_POST){
$sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["pName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender name
$sender_email   = filter_var($_POST["pEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
$phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["pPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$subject        = "$sender_name desea unirse a nuestro equipo";
$message        = filter_var($_POST["pMsg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message

$attachments = $_FILES['pFile'];

$file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
$boundary = md5("sanwebe.com"); 

//construct a message body to be sent to recipient
$message_body =  "$sender_name, se comunica con nosotros para unirse a nuestro equipo\n";
$message_body .= "\n";
$message_body .= "Datos del solicitante\n";
$message_body .=  "Nombre: $sender_name\n";
$message_body .=  "Email: $sender_email\n"; 
$message_body .=  "Tel: $phone_number\n";
$message_body .=  "Mensaje: $message\n";

if($file_count > 0){ //if attachment exists
    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
    
    //message text
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body)); 

    //attachments
    for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){       
        if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){
            
            if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) //exit script and output error if we encounter any
            {
                $mymsg = array( 
                1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
                2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
                3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
                4=>"No file was uploaded", 
                6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 
                print  json_encode( array('type'=>'error',$mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]) ); 
                exit;
            }
            
            //get file info
            $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
            $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
            $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];
            
            //read file 
            $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
            fclose($handle);
            $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)
            
            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
            $body .= $encoded_content; 
        }
    }

}else{ //send plain email otherwise
   $headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
    "Reply-To: ".$sender_email. "\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $body = $message_body;
}
    
$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{  
    echo 1;     
    // print json_encode(array('type'=>'done', 'text' => 'Thank you for your email'));
    // exit;
}else{
    echo 0;
    // print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));  
    // exit;
}
}
```

Comment: If you comment this `// print json_encode(...)` in php script then you have to comment this `dataType : "json"` in ajax call too.