# How do I get my contact form to send an email on submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm expanding upon a template I found online, and I'm currently working on the contact page. I cannot seem to get the form to send the email to my address despite the email address being set within the PHP config. It just comes up with a predefined error message. How do I rectify this?

I've changed the email address within the config.PHP file, I've taken a look at the javascript but I don't want to delete something crucial.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <title>Built By Bizarro: Contact</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="description" content="Built By Zane Donaghey" />
      <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP" />
      <meta name="author" content="Zane Donaghey" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='css/clear.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='css/common.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='css/carouFredSel.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='css/animated-headline.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='css/sm-clean.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='style.css' />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
                <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body class="page">

      <table class="doc-loader">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <img src="images/3.gif" alt="Loading...">
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="menu-wraper center-relative">
          <nav id="header-main-menu" class="big-menu">
              <ul class="main-menu sm sm-clean">
                  <li>
                      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="about.html">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="menu-social">
              <a href="https://twitter.com/BuiltByBizarro/">
                  <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
              </a>
              <a href="http://linkedin.com/in/builtbybizarro/">
                  <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
              </a>
              <a href="http://facebook.com/BuiltByBizarro/">
                  <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
              </a>
              <a href="http://instagram.com/BuiltByBizarro/">
                  <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <header class="header-holder center-relative relative">
          <div class="header-logo">
              <a href="index.html">
                  <img src="images/BBBLogo.png" alt="Built By Bizarro">
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="header-txt">
              <h1 class="entry-title">
                  <span class="entry-title cd-headline letters type">
                      <span>Bizarrely</span>
                      <span class="cd-words-wrapper waiting">
                          <b class="is-visible">creative.</b>
                          <b>efficient.</b>
                          <b>innovative.</b>
                          <b>dedicated.</b>
                      </span>
                      <span class="sec-line">That's what sets me apart from my competition.</span>
                      <span style="color:#f271ab; font-weight: 700;">Built By Bizarro</span>
                  </span>
              </h1>
          </div>

            <div class="toggle-holder absolute">
                <div id="toggle" class="">
                    <div class="first-menu-line"></div>
                    <div class="second-menu-line"></div>
                    <div class="third-menu-line"></div>
                    <div class="fourth-menu-line"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </header>


        <div id="content" class="site-content">
            <article>
                <div class="content-1170 center-relative">
                    <div class="one_half ">
                        <p>For pricing enquiries, send me an email using this form</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>Because they are hard, because that goal will serve to organize and measure the best of our energies and skills, because that challenge is one that we are willing to accept, one we are unwilling to postpone and one.</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>Which we intend to win. With a warning label this big, you know they gotta be fun. Bring me the forms I need to fill out to have her taken away. I decline the title of iron cook and accept the lesser title of zinc saucier, which I just made up. Dinosaurs are extinct today because they lacked opposable thumbs and the brainpower to build a space program. Houston, Tranquillity Base here.</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>
                            <span style="color: #f375ad;">Address:</span>&nbsp;<strong>New York, NY, United States</strong>
                            <br>
                            <span style="color: #f375ad;">Phone:</span> <strong>+1 234-567-890</strong>
                            <br>
                            <span style="color: #f375ad;">Hours:</span> <strong>6:00 am – 2:00 am</strong>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one_half last">
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <p><input id="name" type="text" name="your-name" placeholder="Name"></p>
                            <p><input id="contact-email" type="email" name="your-email" placeholder="Email"></p>
                            <p><input id="subject" type="text" name="your-subject" placeholder="Subject"></p>
                            <p><textarea id="message" name="your-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></p>
                            <p><input type="submit" onClick="SendMail()" value="SEND"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </article>


        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="content-1170 center-relative">
                <ul id="footer-sidebar">
                    <li class="widget">
                        <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
                              <a href="https://twitter.com/BuiltByBizarro/">
                                  <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
                              </a>
                              <a href="http://linkedin.com/in/builtbybizarro/">
                                  <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
                              </a>
                              <a href="http://facebook.com/BuiltByBizarro/">
                                  <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                              </a>
                              <a href="http://instagram.com/BuiltByBizarro/">
                                  <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!--Load JavaScript-->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.fitvids.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js'></script>
        <script src='js/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.0-packed.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
        <script src='js/main-headline.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* CONTACT */

.contact-form
{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact-form input[type=text], .contact-form input[type=email], .contact-form textarea
{
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.contact-form input[name="your-name"]
{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.contact-form textarea
{
    height: 150px;
}

.contact-form input[type=submit]
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: color .2s linear, border-color .2s linear;
}
.contact-form input[type=submit]:hover
{
    color: #f271ab;
    border-color: #f271ab;
}

.contact-form input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder, .contact-form input[type=email]::-webkit-input-placeholder, .contact-form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.contact-form input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder, .contact-form input[type=email]::-moz-placeholder, .contact-form textarea::-moz-placeholder
{
    font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.contact-form input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder, .contact-form input[type=email]:-ms-input-placeholder, .contact-form textarea:-ms-input-placeholder
{
    font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.contact-form input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder, .contact-form input[type=email]:-moz-placeholder, .contact-form textarea:-moz-placeholder
{
    font-family:  'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    opacity: 1;
}
/* END CONTACT */
```

JS:

```
var SendMail = function () {

    var emailVal = jQuery('#contact-email').val();

    if (isValidEmailAddress(emailVal)) {
        var params = {
            'action': 'SendMessage',
            'name': jQuery('#name').val(),
            'email': jQuery('#contact-email').val(),
            'subject': jQuery('#subject').val(),
            'message': jQuery('#message').val()
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/sendMail.php",
            data: params,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    if (responseObj.ResponseData)
                    {
                        alert(responseObj.ResponseData);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //xhr.status : 404, 303, 501...
                var error = null;
                switch (xhr.status)
                {
                    case "301":
                        error = "Redirection Error!";
                        break;
                    case "307":
                        error = "Error, temporary server redirection!";
                        break;
                    case "400":
                        error = "Bad request!";
                        break;
                    case "404":
                        error = "Page not found!";
                        break;
                    case "500":
                        error = "Server is currently unavailable!";
                        break;
                    default:
                        error = "Unexpected error, please try again later. Alternatively, you can still contact me @BuiltByBizarro on most major forms of social media.";
                }
                if (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            }
        });
    } else
    {
        alert('Your email is not in valid format');
    }


};
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include_once (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php');

//Initial response is NULL
$response = null;

//Initialize appropriate action and return as HTML response
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $action = $_POST["action"];

    switch ($action) {
        case "SendMessage": {
                if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["subject"]) && isset($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["subject"]) && !empty($_POST["message"])) {

                    $message = "Name:" . $_POST["name"]. "<br/><br/>";
                    $message .= $_POST["message"];
                    $message .= "<br/><br/>";

                    $response = (SendEmail($message, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["email"], $email)) ? 'Message Sent' : "Sending Message Failed";
                } else {
                    $response = "Sending Message Failed";
                }
            }
            break;
        default: {
                $response = "Invalid action is set! Action is: " . $action;
            }
    }
}


if (isset($response) && !empty($response) && !is_null($response)) {
    echo '{"ResponseData":' . json_encode($response) . '}';
}

function SendEmail($message, $subject, $from, $to) {
    $isSent = false;
    // Content-type header
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    // $headers .= 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if (mail) {
        $isSent = true;
    }
    return $isSent;
}

?>
```

```
<?php

//SITE GLOBAL CONFIGURATION
$email = "admin@builtbybizarro.com";   //<-- Your email

?>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Comment: I appreciate your reply John, I just included all of the relevant code for the entire page. I've actually cut down about 70% of the code involved. The problem lies somewhere within the javascript or PHP. I just want to be able to submit on the form and send an email.

Comment: Use PHP's built-in `mail` function.

Comment: We understand your concern Zee. The first questions on this site are always difficult to gauge how much code to supply. More is better than none, but it's important to try to keep it minimal. It would be best, for instance, to determine whether or not it's JS or PHP that's causing an issue. To do this you would simply run your JS and verify it works by logging your values. If that all looks correct, you can verify it's getting to your PHP script by printing something when your PHP initially runs. If that works, then it's probably your `mail` function. Then you know it's PHP which is specific.

Comment: At any point in that debug chain if you get stung by an error, you can ask a question, and because you've compartmentalized it, it will be much more specific and easier to assist with, instead of  **"Something in my project in one of these different languages isn't working. I'm getting an error."** - which brings up the last point. If you're getting an error, please share it when asking :)

Comment: @zfrisch Thanks, I understand a lot better now. I don't know why I didn't think to check the console. I get an error which states:

jquery.js:4 Access to XMLHttpRequest at '(directory)/php/sendMail.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

So it's something to do with jquery, but that's a big jungle of code in itself. Have you ever had a similar error before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your question, at least how you phrase it, is how you can send email with PHP so the other code is quite unnecessary and just clutters it (not a big problem, just a bad habit).

Now that we have that out of the way, the default PHP `mail()` function does not allow for SMTP authentication, which is a problem since you need that for even the most basic security measurements.

Mail in PHP, by my experience, can be a real pain sometimes and the most user-friendly and feature packed solution would be to use a library like [PHP mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [PEAR](https://www.lifewire.com/send-email-from-php-script-using-smtp-authentication-and-ssl-1171197). A good example for PHP mailer is on the linked GitHub page and for PEAR can be found [here](https://www.lifewire.com/send-email-from-php-script-using-smtp-authentication-and-ssl-1171197)