# Mail Function is giving false return in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I have tried sending email from a basic html form by php mail() function and It has given me false return

```
Code:
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $name1 = $_POST['last_name']; 
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $company=$_POST['lead_object'];
        $skype= $_POST['skype_id'];
        $to = 'himanshu@webkidukan.com';
        $subject = 'Advertiser Form Details';
        $from = 'ssing648@gmail.com';

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Create email headers
        $headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        // Compose a simple HTML email message
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Sir</h1>';
        $message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Details of Advertiser Form</p>';
        $message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;"><?php $title . " " . $name . " " . "?>wrote the following:"<?php . "\n\n" . $name . "\n\n" . $name1 . "\n\n" .$email . "\n\n" .$phone . "\n\n" .$company. "\n\n" .$skype. "\n\n"?> </p>';
        $message .= '</body></html>';
        $t = mail($to, $from, $message, $headers,$subject);
        var_dump($t);exit;
        if ($t) {
            echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . " .We will contact you shortly.";

        }else{
           echo "Failed to send email. Please try again later";
        }

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Thanks for filling out our form! We will look over your message and get back to you soon.')</script>";    

    echo "<script> window.location.href = 'advertiser.php';</script>";  
}

 ?>
```

I have this issue in three forms together , hence posting one for the understanding the mistake, that I am doing. Can anyone of you help me with the same.Or should I go for the SMTP mail option.Also I am sending the form details in mail to the user.So also check that the way to send the flyer is right or not.

Comment: if you are trying to do it on localhost then you have to do additional settings...

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie It is live sir.....I know the settings for localhost.

Comment: @Himanshu have you set SMTP settings in your config file?

Comment: No, I have been sending mails without SMTP details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

There are some unwanted PHP tags while appending message. try like this

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Sir</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Details of Advertiser Form</p>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">'.$title." ".$name." wrote the following:"."\n\n".$name."\n\n".$name1."\n\n".$email."\n\n".$phone."\n\n".$company."\n\n".$skype."\n\n".'</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

Comment: Okay..I will try

Comment: I am able to send the mail, now....But how can i call the PHP values in $message. $message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Sir</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Details of Advertiser Form</p>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">'.$title." ".$name." wrote the following:"."\n\n".$name."\n\n".$name1."\n\n".$email."\n\n".$phone."\n\n".$company."\n\n".$skype."\n\n".'</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

Comment: @Himanshu `$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;"><?php $title . "` Dude, that's not how concetanation works in php, it should be `$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">'.$title.'`

Comment: Cool. enjoy coding!

Comment: If my answer helped you kindly accept it. else leave it