# Trying to send emails using a contact form

Tags: php, email

So I'm trying to send a mail from my contactform to my mailadress. My problem is that when i press the mail it doesn't work.

This is the error message i get:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projekt_1\php\send_form_email.php on line 12

As my minor programming and hosting skills tells me i need to change something in my php.ini file but I'm not sure how or what i need to do.

Comment: Make sure you are following the correct way. refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: Did you install a mailserver?

Comment: "i need to change something in my php.ini file"....no, you need to install and configure a mailserver on your machine. Or, probably more easy, switch to using something like PHPMailer instead of mail() and connect to a 3rd party SMTP server.

Comment: 1) Windows does not come with a MailServer pre installed. 2) The PHP `mail()` function does not send email, it just passes it to a mail server for transmittion. So if you have no mail server it wont send mail

Comment: **Good News** XAMPP comes with a utility called `sendmail.exe` See the Dup Q&A and it will tell you how to configure it or better still see @ADyson comment and use `PHPMailer`