# PHP Confirmation Email after filling out Contact Form

Tags: php

I've created a contact page for a project im working on and im having trouble getting it to send a confirmation email to the user. I have the function defined on my emailer page along with the code that sends the contact form to me

```
public function sendEmail(){ //this will format and send an email to the smtp server
        $to = $this->getSenderEmail();
        $subject = $this->getSubject();
        $message = $this->getMessage();
        $headers = "From: <contact@tristonnearmyer.com >";
        $from = $this->getCustomerInfo();
        //it will use the php mail()
        return mail($to,$subject,$message,$from);
}
public function sendConfEmail(){
        $userEmail = $this->getRecipientEmail();
        $confSubject = "confirmation";
        $confMessage = "thank you";
        return mail($userEmail, $confSubject, $confMessage);
}
```

then the functions are used on the contact page

```
echo $emailTest->sendEmail(); //send email to SMTP server
echo $emailTest->sendConfEmail(); //send confirmation email
```

I can't seem to figure out why one is working while the other isn't

Comment: Which one works? `$headers` is never used. The native PHP mail function has poor error reporting I recommend Swift or PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, you need to call the function `sendConfEmail` after `sendEmail` success. Also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php) you need to modify the header. But base on user3783243 commend better change to PHPMailer or use swift

```
public function sendEmail(){ //this will format and send an email to the smtp server
    $to = $this->getSenderEmail();
    $subject = $this->getSubject();
    $message = $this->getMessage();
    $from = $this->getCustomerInfo();
    $headers = 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: youremailhere@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $sendMail =  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if($sendMail){
        // Call the function send confirmation
        $this->sendConfEmail();
    }else{
        echo 'failed sent the email';
    }

}

public function sendConfEmail(){
    $userEmail = $this->getRecipientEmail();
    $confSubject = "confirmation";
    $confMessage = "thank you";
    $from = $this->getCustomerInfo();
    $headers = 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: youremailhere@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    return mail($userEmail, $confSubject, $confMessage,$headers);
}
```