# HTML Form to Email + 3rd Party Form Backend Platform

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a form using **Webflow** and used **Getform.io** for the endpoint URL for the backend platform.

Everything is working perfectly fine with all the data capturing and file uploads.

However, I am trying to make the form to send an email to user's inbox with the data capture from the form together with the file uploaded.

How can this be done using PHP or any relevant method??

So now it is as below:

**Form A** (created in Webflow, Getform.io endpoint URL using POST method, have file upload capability)

I need **Form A** to be able to send an email to user's inbox too with data and file uploaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you checked to see if your question has been answered already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php looks very similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use palabra.io to do this. We have a tutorial just for Webflow you can read here: https://blog.palabra.io/how-to-send-a-confirmation-email-when-someone-submits-a-webflow-form (I'm the builder btw).

Comment: I tried checking out the link. But it doesn't do what I needed. =(