# PHPMailer not posting

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I am trying to use PHP mailer on my site however it doesn't post to the email

Here is the code:

Top:

Where it sends:

```
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        //Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        
        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = 'maileremail';                     //SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = 'mailerpassword';                               //SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
        
            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('maileremail', 'Mailer');
            $mail->addAddress(myemail', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
        
            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
            $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        
            $mail->send();
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
              ?>
```

I have tried everything but it still won't post.

Comment: Search for "send email php"?

Comment: Hello! Mate you need show us the code and what you tried rather than straight asking away. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-can-i-send-an-email-using-php)

Comment: You have verbose debug output enabled, great, that should help, but you forgot to show us that output. "*it still won't post*" - what does this mean?  The whole form won't `POST`?  The form `POST`s fine and creates your DB records but the email doesn't arrive?  Pls be specific, explain the problem in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
mail('bubu@yoghi.com', 'Subject', 'Text message...');
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: @HimanshiThakur dear Ben Howard, read the documentation for an adequate explanation :-)

Comment: As @Himanshi explained, [code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).