# Run a php script inside a laravel project

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I have the following code in html, a simple email form:

```
                <form class="main_form" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
                    <div class="row">
                     
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="title" type="text" name="Title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="message" type="text" name="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <button class="send" >send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And this is the script I want to run everytime you hit "send" (sendmail.php)

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submitted_form'])){
    $subject = $_POST['Title'];
    $message = "Email : $_POST['Email'] Message: $_POST['Message']";
    $headers = "From:abc@xyz.com";
    send_mail($subject,$message,$headers);
  }
function send_mail( $subject, $message, $headers){
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-can-i-send-an-email-using-php
    $to = "bordadoscreativos.02@gmail.com";
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
}
?>
```

Now my problem is that everytime I hit send, the URL changes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendmail.php and it throws a 404. what should I do? Create a controller for sendmail.php? I already tried creating a route inside web.php for sendmail.php but it still doesn't work.

Comment: instead of creating sendmail.php .create a method in controller

Comment: @JohnLobo and how do I redirect my html code to that controller?

Comment: you need to create routes .just learn basics of laravel first then work on it.so it help you to solve most of the issues yourself. If you google it lots of laravel resources available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create send_mail.blade.php in resource/view path

```
<form class="main_form" method="post" action="/send_mail">
      @csrf
                <div class="row">
                 
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="title" type="text" name="Title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="message" type="text" name="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <button class="send" >send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Then create new class SendMailController.php in app\Http\Controllers path

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\SendMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BankCashController extends Controller
{
    public function send_mail(Request $request) {
        $to = "bordadoscreativos.02@gmail.com";
        $headers = "From:abc@xyz.com";
        $subject = $request->get('Subject');
        $message = $request->get('Email') . "</br>" . $request->get('Message');

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
        } else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
        }
    }
}
```

Add this route in routes\web.php

```
Route::post('/send_mail', 'app\Http\Controllers\SendMailControllere@send_mail');
```

You need alos create SendMail.php model in app\Models path

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SendMail extends Model
{
    protected $guard_name = 'web';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'email',
        'message',
        'to',
        ... //add all columns of your table
    ];
 }
```

Comment: and what would the model contain? the meat of the code is already inside the controller. just that and I'll accept your answer

Comment: also it returns a 419 error. I think its because its missing a  CSRF token in the html form. I'll research on it and try to add later

Comment: Oh, Yes. You should add @csrf inside form block.

Answer (score 1):

You have a project structure issue here, if you are using Laravel you have to separate in MVC pattern, it means that all logic have to be in controller not in your views.

Besides if you want to use php code in your views you could use blade, blade is usefull for conditions, bucles, etc etc.

Lear more about how laravel project structure and blade
[Doc Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade)